# catching mole in at least move

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that there are 4 hole on the soil surface and there is a mole underground. you want to cath this mole with a trap. if this mole rises to the surface using hole 2,a day later it rises to the surface using hole 1 or hole 3 which are neighbour to hole 2.In the same way, if it uses hole 1, a day later it uses hole 2 which is only neighbour to hole 1.how can you catch this mole in at least move?

Comment: Do we know where the mole rises to the surface every day?

Comment: For instance, if we plant a trap over hole 1, and the mole rises to hole 3, will we know that it rose to hole 3 ?

Comment: yes, you know at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

If the mole ever rears its head from 1 or 4, you'll surely catch it the next day. Hence in all other cases it is best for you to assume that it will avoid holes 1 and 4.

The following guarantees a catch at day three or earlier:

- On day one do not place a trap anywhere; or if you feel lucky, put it anywhere.
- On day two, put you trap to hole 2 if the mole was at 1 or 3, and put it to hole 3 otherwise.
- On day three, switch betwen from 2 to 3 or from 3 to 2, depending on where your trap was the day before.

To see that this is minimal, observe that it is impossible to predict the moles appearance on the first day. And if the mole appeared on either 2 or 3 (and the mole would have survived at least one of these choices, no matter where your trap was on day one), it is impossible to safely predict its appearance on day two.